# how to submit a geolocation field via the API create command?

Tags: soap-api, php, geolocation

I'm starting out using the enterprise API for PHP with a simple create command...

```
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create($insertArray, 'customobject__c');
```

My $insertArray includes a value to go into the custom objects geocode field.

The problem is that i'm simply now sure how to format the two lat/lng values I have and whatever I try results in the following error

> Unable to create/update fields: Location__c. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.

Btw, I'm sure this is nothing to do with security as I had the same error on other fields that were simply miss-formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the latitude and longitude separately; the main field is a compound field that can only be read, similar to how Account.ShippingAddress combines all of the address fields.

Sample:

```
customobject__c.Location__latitude__s = latitude
customobject__c.Location__longitude__s = longitude
```

More information can be found in the documentation for the [Geolocation Compound Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_geolocation.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Mike Chale, one thing, what would the format be in PHP?

I'm submitting via an array that is being compiled and full stops are not valid syntax.  Ie

$insertArray[0]->Location__c.Location__latitude__s = $locationLat;

I can't find an example anywhere showing this...

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with PHP, but I think it'd be `$insertArray[0]=>Array([Field1]=>value1, [Field2]=>value2, . . .)`

Comment: It works as standard without square brackets, but either way, with or without them,  adding a full stop is invalid syntax.

Comment: You need to convert it to valid PHP; the example above was meant as a generic sample of how to use the fields.

Comment: I understood that, I'm just expressing I don't know the PHP syntax but I'm working on that now...

Comment: For the record, although I didn't need to add an item with a full stop in it in the end, its done in PHP like this: {'name.example'}

Answer (score -2):

So @Mike Chale gave me the key piece of info that the geolocation field is a compound field.   The syntax I need is different though as this is the custom geolocation field.

```
$insertArray[0]->Location__latitude__s;
```

Unlike all my other custom fields that are suffixed with __C, this doesn't need that although it is a custom field and __latitude__s or __longitude__s is suffixed instead.

More info here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&language=en

Comment: He took the time to answer your question, show the same etiquette and mark his answer as correct, adding any additional information to his answer.